# Why is Chart js first bar too small or not showing at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Hi I am trying to show some bar charts using charts js, my problem is that the first column isn't showing properly.

This is my code:

```
var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: true
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      display: false
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
};
var dataD = {
  labels: ["2020-09-01 18:05:33", "2020-10-13 11:08:28"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "PA",
    data: [132, 139],
    backgroundColor: "#4cb6cb"
  }]
};

var methods = new Chart($("#line192"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: dataD,
  animation: true,
  options: options
});
```

And this is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/imurphy/ajgq84mw/1/)

Any thoughts? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the axes start at your minimum value.  Set `ticks.beginAtZero` to `true` on your Y-axis to display and your first bar will be visible:

```js
var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      display: false
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
};
var dataD = {
  labels: ["2020-09-01 18:05:33", "2020-10-13 11:08:28"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "PA",
    data: [132, 139],
    backgroundColor: "#4cb6cb"
  }]
};

var methods = new Chart($("#line192"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: dataD,
  animation: true,
  options: options
});
```

[Here is the fixed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/typpo/q0w1rhsx/)

Comment: Yup. And you could also do `ticks: { min: 100 }` or any number, including zero, if you want more control.